# Flex 4 - center popup

Tags: apache-flex, popup

How can I center popup window in flex 4 ?

I have tried:

```
PopUpManager.addPopUp(AlertPopUp,DisplayObject(spark.components.Application), true);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(AlertPopUp);
```

but it's problem with conversion Application->DisplayObject.

Please help :)

Answer (score 5):

```
PopUpManager.addPopUp(AlertPopUp, FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as DisplayObject, true);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(AlertPopUp);
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/10/23/displaying-a-popup-spark-titlewindow-container-in-flex-4/) link contains an example which works for me. Can you try the same? If its not working for you,post your elaborated code block to check how you have coded.

Comment: using
DisplayObject(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication)
solve problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Also PopUpAnchor is worth checking if you need to position relatively to some specific component, let's say a button.